# javascript-aware html parser for Python ~

Tags: javascript, python, lxml

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<a href="http://www.google.com">f*** js</a>');
    document.write("f*** js!");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<a href="http://www.google.com">f*** js</a>');
    document.write("f*** js!");
    </script>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com">f*** js</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want use xpath to catch all  lable object in the html page above...

```
In [1]: import lxml.html as H

In [2]: f = open("test.html","r")

In [3]: c = f.read()

In [4]: doc = H.document_fromstring(c)

In [5]: doc.xpath('//a')
Out[5]: [<Element a at a01d17c>]

In [6]: a = doc.xpath('//a')[0]

In [7]: a.getparent()
Out[7]: <Element div at a01d41c>
```

I only get one  don't generate by js～
but firefox xpath checker can find all  lable!?

> > > https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hSug.png

how to do that??? thx~!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
function over(){
a.innerHTML="mouse me"
}
function out(){
a.innerHTML="<a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a>"
}
</script>
<body><li id="a"onmouseover="over()" onmouseout="out()">mouse me</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: removed profanity as it served nothing..

Comment: You will have to parse and interpret the js before parsing the HTML. Have you seen http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/?

Comment: Your javascript, as given, makes no sense - you are writing links into the document's head? From lxml's point of view, anything in document.write is a string constant, not to be parsed.

Comment: BTW, document.write() is not allowed in XML documents. You must use the DOM API.

Comment: I think the title should be "javascript-aware html parser for Python"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a clue about javascript-aware parser in python but you can use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to do the job. The idea is not mine so I'm leaving you the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390992/javascript-parser-in-python).

It's actually quite cool because you can optimize your parser to selectively choose what instruction needs to be parsed (and executed).

Comment: Nice! And from the same question you linked, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey/ seems to be consideration worth as well..

Answer (score 0):

In Java there is [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp). I don't know any Javascript-aware HTML parser for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Searching google for "javascript standalone runtime", I found [jslibs](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/): a "standalone JavaScript development runtime environment for using JavaScript as a general-purpose scripting language", based on "[SpiderMonkey](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/SpiderMonkey) library that is Gecko's JavaScript engine".

Sounds great! I haven't tested yet, but it seems like this will allow you to run the javascript code you find in the page. I don't know how much it will be tricky, though..

Comment: Not quite... it's just the language bindings, but doesn't have the DOM API. Most real-world javascript still won't work in it. By the time you add all the parts you need, you will have... a browser. Or, the closest thing I know if is [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).