# Python regex. Match js function body with another nested function(s)

Tags: javascript, python, regex, python-2.7

There is following js function:

```
function foo() 
{ 
    function bar(objArr) 
    { 
        var ts=''; 
        for (i=0; i<objArr.length; i++) 
        {
            if (objArr[i].checked == true) 
                ts +=objArr[i].value;
        } 
        return ts;
    } 

    tmb=document.getElementById('tmb');        
    x=bar(tmb.vn); 
    return x.substr(6,1); 
}
```

How do i match foo() function body?

Comment: Instead of a regex, look for a [JavaScript parser in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/390992/222914).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(?<=function foo\(\))(\s|.)*
```