# Extracting string constant from source code in a string using regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, lexical-analysis

How can I get a string constant from source code in a string?

For example, here is the source code I am trying to process:

```
var v = "this is string constant + some numbers and \" is also included "
```

I am unable to get everything inside quotation marks. by using this regular expression: `"(.*?)"`.

I can't get `var`, `v`, `=` or anything else except string character.

Comment: Python doesn't use "var."

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense -- what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse some other programming language using Python. Don't do this using regular expressions; it will only lead to heartache. Use a proper parser.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390992/javascript-parser-in-python

Comment: @tehsockz I know that but I want to add this in my language.

Comment: @tehsockz I want to extract string constant in quotation marks

Comment: @Kindall thanks I did that for Identifiers, numbers, etc... but for String constant I don't know what to do the main problem is " in " "

Comment: Regex is a perfect fit for this. Language parsers are *built* using regular expressions, at least for parts of the job, and this is one.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I need an example :)

Comment: Could you provide a more clear example of what the desired output should be given the input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lookbehind, to make sure the " is not preceded by a \

```
import re

data = 'var v = "this is string constant + some numbers and \" is also included "\r\nvar v = "and another \"line\" "'
matches = re.findall( r'= "(.*(?<!\\))"', data, re.I | re.M)
print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['this is string constant + some numbers and " is also included ', 'and another "line" ']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to match an opening quote, then anything that's either an escaped character or a normal character (except quotes and backslashes), and then a closing quote:

```
"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"
```

Comment: Yes, was about to write that. There's a difference between _parsing_ a text completely and _extracting_ just some bits from it.

Answer (score 0):

For get everything inside quotation marks you can try this:
`"\".+?\""` with `re.findall()`