# Can I use BeautifulSoup to dig into inline JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a block of data from a series of pages that have the data tucked away in a JSON object inside of a script tag. I'm fairly comfortable with BeautifulSoup, but I think I might be barking up the wrong tree trying to use it to get data from JavaScript.

The structure of the pages is, roughly, this:

```
...
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var data = $.data(graph_selector, [
         { data: charts.createData("Stuff I want")}
    ])};
</script>
```

The head and body have a zillion scripts each, but there's only one `var data` per page. I'm not sure how I'd identify this particular `<script>` for BeautifulSoup except by the presence of `var data`

Can I do this? Or do I need another tool?

Comment: I would find the raw javascript string using BeautifulSoup and then use regex to get the 'Stuff I want' [Somewhat related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21069605/1189040) or [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21069526/1189040)

Comment: But then the value of BeautifulSoup in the equation is fairly low. It allows you to find the `<script>` nodes but that wasn't very hard in the first place. (Properly, you should ignore any commented-out ones, but this is hardly a huge problem in reality.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` is an HTML parser, it cannot parse javascript code.

Here are the options you have:

1. use a javascript parser like [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit)

   ```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   from slimit import ast
   from slimit.parser import Parser
   from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor

   data = """
   <script>
       var data = $.data(graph_selector, [
            { data: charts.createData("Stuff I want")}
       ]);
   </script>
   """

   soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
   script = soup.find('script')


   parser = Parser()
   tree = parser.parse(script.text)
   print next(node.args[0].value for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree)
              if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionCall) and node.identifier.identifier.value == 'createData')
   # prints "Stuff I want"
   ```

   Note that I had to cut down the script for the sake of a working example and due to parsing errors. Might not work for your real script contents, please check.
2. use regular expressions (the easiest option yet unreliable so don't use it in production code unless you have control over the JS code too and can make the guarantees needed):

   ```
   import re
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   data = """
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   var data = $.data(graph_selector, [{data: charts.createData("Stuff I want")}])};
   </script>
   """

   soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
   script = soup.find('script')

   pattern = r'charts.createData\("(.*?)"\)'
   print re.search(pattern, script.text).group(1)  # prints "Stuff I want"
   ```
3. let smth execute the javascript code: [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) (real browser), or [`V8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/v8), or [`PyExecJS`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExecJS)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev thanks for the important notes. This is why I've put this option under a second position, also added a working example for the first option.