# Extracting Page title using beatifulsoup with Python 3 does not return correct title

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to extract the Title of the Stewart international Airport (https://www.swfny.com/). My code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.swfny.com/"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.title.string)
```

In the html code of the page I see the following title declaration

```
<title>Home - SWF - Stewart International Airport</title>
```

I am expecting to see the following text as title "Home - SWF - Stewart International Airport" as output. But I do not get this as the output, instead I am getting "Aviation".

Comment: It looks like the page is being created largely using javascript. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069294/parse-the-javascript-returned-from-beautifulsoup) might help.