# BeautifulSoup cannot find data from page

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull data from my NFL Fantasy football league using the following code

```
site = "http://fantasy.nfl.com/league/XXXXXXX"
req = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"html5lib")
all_tables=soup.find_all('table')
all_tables
```

But this returns nothing. I looked into what the variable soup returns, and did control-f to search for player names or stats but had no luck. I have looked at other threads, read some documentation, and tried different parsers like "html.parser", "lxml", and "xml". But still can't figure it out.

Could it be that it is impossible to view this data through python?

Answer (score 2):

So most likely the table is loaded through javascript. So beautifulSoup won't pickup the table. What I've done in the past is use selenium and load the page and then you can pick up the tables loaded to javascript. I believe there are some libraries now that combine JavaScript and BeautifulSoup.

Maybe take a look at this:
[Parse the JavaScript returned from BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069294/parse-the-javascript-returned-from-beautifulsoup)

Comment: I went the Selenium route and it seems to be working so far. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jordan I'm glad it worked out!