# Python: unable to get data from json and convert to list

Tags: python, json

I need to get data from a json page and convert it to a list.

```
import json
import requests

j = requests.get('http://www.example.com/Portals/0/StaticData/data.js')
abc = json.loads(j.content)
```

However, error occurred

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

what I need is

```
mylist = ['AALI','ABBA','ABDA'.......]
mylist1 = ['Astra Agro Lestari Tbk','Mahaka Media Tbk','Asuransi Bina Dana Arta Tbk',.......]
```

Comment: That endpoint (that `idx.co.id...` URL) doesn't return JSON, but javascript code with a variable assignment `var symbolsCode = [{"` ... You might wanna look a this thread?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390992/javascript-parser-in-python Maybe it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a valid JSON returned, you can clean it up before reading it in with `json` module:

```
js = j.content.decode("utf-8").split("=")[-1].strip().strip(';')

json.loads(js)

#[{'code': 'AALI', 'name': 'Astra Agro Lestari Tbk'},
# {'code': 'ABBA', 'name': 'Mahaka Media Tbk'},
# {'code': 'ABDA', 'name': 'Asuransi Bina Dana Arta Tbk'},
# {'code': 'ABMM', 'name': 'ABM Investama Tbk'},
# {'code': 'ACES', 'name': 'Ace Hardware Indonesia Tbk'},
# ...
```

To unpack the result into two lists:

```
mylist, mylist1 = zip(*((d['code'], d['name']) for d in json.loads(js)))
```

Comment: It works, but still have 'u' in the mylist and mylist1. Also, can you add explanation for `js = j.content.decode("utf-8").split("=")[-1].strip().strip(';')` and `json.loads(js)`?