# HTML data is hidden from urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib, urlopen

How do I get the real content from this page: 
http://kursuskatalog.au.dk/da/course/74960/105E17-Demokrati-og-diktatur-i-komparativt-perspektiv

All I get from the code below is some links to javascript and CSS files. Is there a way out of this?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://kursuskatalog.au.dk/da/course/74960/105E17-Demokrati-og-diktatur-i-komparativt-perspektiv")
print(html.read())
```

Best regards, Kresten

Answer (score 1):

Content in this URL is created with JavaScript after page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

What is  printed is the 'real' content. If you wanted to see the output of that JavaScript code you would need to fetch all the JavaScript through the `<script></script>` tags and external script and then use a [JavaScript Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390992/javascript-parser-in-python) to read it.  You would not need the CSS scripts for just reading the content as they are just used to style the page.

Unfortunately I can think of no alternative.

I hope I was helpful.