# Beautiful Soup can't find tables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to gather some data from a table on a web page with Python and Beautiful Soup. When I make a selection from the page, however, I'm getting different results than I get in the browser. Specifically, the tables are missing completely. Here's a screenshot of the table in the inspector of Firefox dev tools:

[image: Screenshot of web page and inspector]

And here's the output that I get from Beautiful Soup:

[image: Screenshot of IDE with output]

I've tried using urllib instead of requests, and I've tried using different HTML parsers, (html.parser and lxml). All give the same results. Any advice on what might be happening here and how I might get around it to access the data from the table?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import tabula
import html5lib

knox = requests.get("https://covid.knoxcountytn.gov/case-count.html")
knox_soup = BeautifulSoup(knox.text, 'html5lib')
knox_confirmed = knox_soup.find('div', id='covid_cases').prettify()

print(knox_confirmed)
```

Comment: please [edit] your question and include your code as a `code` instead of `img`, so we can manually check and verify

Comment: Chances are that thetable is being populated using javascript which makes further ajaz calls to get the table content.This javascript isn’t (can’t be) executed when you retrieve it with `requests` - you’ll probably have to use a browser-simulation like selectium which can execute javascript, so you’ll possibly be able to collect the table Good luck!

Comment: And yes don’t put images of code/text into a question - paste the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable javascript when you visit https://covid.knoxcountytn.gov/case-count.html and you will see no table. As @barny said the table is generated with javascript so you can't parse it with BeautifulSoup (at least not easily, see [How to call JavaScript function using BeautifulSoup and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603339/how-to-call-javascript-function-using-beautifulsoup-and-python)).

Comment: The post you linked was exactly what I needed! Using requests-html to render the page's JavaScript got me all the info I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Website is loaded via `JavaScript`, so you can't use `requestes` to render the `JS` for you. You can use `selenium` or `requests_html` etc.

As for now, I've been able to track from where the data is fetched. by checking the `XHR` traffic been made.

So we can use `pandas.read_csv()` as the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://covid.knoxcountytn.gov/includes/covid_cases.csv")

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: That's a brilliant solution. I never even considered that I could fetch the data directly from the same source the website does. Thanks for the advice!