# How to use Beautiful Soup to get function in <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, beautifulsoup

In a given .html page , I have a script tag like so:

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

How can I use Beautiful Soup to get 2nd parameter in .open function?

> This case is "ajax_info.txt"

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is not built for this.  It is built to parse html not JavaScript or any other web languages.

The easier way is to use  a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

You can also parse JavaScript using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html), or without regex as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390992/javascript-parser-in-python#)

---

Edit:

**Example:**

> I do not know how to use a headless browser although this is probably the best way ahead, however I do know enough regex to create a quick and dirty example that will work for the example you listed above.

```
b = """function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  this.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
xhttp.send();
}""" 

# Get value between <script></script> using  BeautifulSoup and store in "b"

import re
a = re.compile('"GET", "[\S ]+"')
c = a.search(b).group()
print(c[8:-1])
```

Comment: @baroad  I included an exaple.  It needs improvement as I said above but it gives you a good idea (and it works) of how it can be done.  If you are going to do this regularly/with very large JavaScript scripts I strongly suggest learning a headless browser, it will be  a lot easier.