# How to scrape a string representation of a nested list?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to record the DataCamp courses I have done by using a web scraper. First kudos to this guy, who has [built something along my needs](http://goodbody.io/webscraping-datacamp-courses-iii-copy/).

However, recently DataCamp has made changes to their website and now the comprehensive course data is not in JSON anymore, but seems to be stored as a string representation of a nested list.

If you take a look at the [source](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/free-introduction-to-r/chapter-6-lists?ex=3#skiponboarding) of one of the chapter pages, the first element in the body is:

```
<body><script>window.PRELOADED_STATE = "[&quot;~#iM&quot;,[&quot;preFetchedData&quot;,[&quot;^0&quot;,[&quot;course&quot;,[&quot;^0&quot;,[&quot;status&quot;,&quot;SUCCESS&quot;,&quot;data&quot;,[&quot;^ &quot;,&quot;id&quot;,58,&quot;title&quot;,&quot;Introduction to R ...
```

So the original scraper was able to rely on JSON and extracting the information via the dict keys. There is an idea field, so probably I should be able to extract the data once I have a list of lists of the underlying data.

I tried extracting the string representation via `ast.literal_eval`, but that did not work. Any idea how I could make this list usable?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but the answer is probably going to be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52903508/604048).