# Python - How to print out one line out of a text

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

So I have been working out with abit of bs4 and managed to print out a text. Right now I managed to print out `var ajaxsearch` which init comes alot more.

I have written a code where it prints out all that contains javascript and print out where `var ajaxsearch` starts withit:

```
  try:
        product_li_tags = bs4.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
    except Exception:
        product_li_tags = []

    special_code = ''
    for s in product_li_tags:
        if s.text.strip().startswith('var ajaxsearch'):
            special_code = s.text
            break

    print(special_code)
```

and I am getting an output of:

```
var ajaxsearch = false;
var combinationsFromController ={
  "224114": {
    "attributes_values": {
      "4": "5.5"
    },
    "attributes": [
      22
    ],

    "unit_impact": 0,
    "minimal_quantity": "1",
    "date_formatted": "",
    "available_date": "",
    "id_image": -1,
    "list": "'22'"
  },
  "224140": {
    "attributes_values": {
      "4": "6"
    },
    "attributes": [
      23
    ],
    "unit_impact": 0,
    "minimal_quantity": "1",
    "date_formatted": "",
    "available_date": "",
    "id_image": -1,
    "list": "'23'"
  },
  "224160": {
    "attributes_values": {
      "4": "6.5"
    },
    "attributes": [
      24
    ],
    "unit_impact": 0,
    "minimal_quantity": "1",
    "date_formatted": "",
    "available_date": "",
    "id_image": -1,
    "list": "'24'"
  },
  "224139": {
    "attributes_values": {
      "4": "7"
    },
    "attributes": [
      25
    ],
    "unit_impact": 0,
    "minimal_quantity": "1",
    "date_formatted": "",
    "available_date": "",
    "id_image": -1,
    "list": "'25'"
  },
  "224138": {
    "attributes_values": {
      "4": "7.5"
    },
    "attributes": [
      26
    ],
    "unit_impact": 0,
    "minimal_quantity": "1",
    "date_formatted": "",
    "available_date": "",
    "id_image": -1,
    "list": "'26'"
  },
  "224113": {
    "attributes_values": {
      "4": "8"
    },
    "attributes": [
      27
    ],
    "unit_impact": 0,
    "minimal_quantity": "1",
    "date_formatted": "",
    "available_date": "",
    "id_image": -1,
    "list": "'27'"
  },
  "224129": {
    "attributes_values": {
      "4": "8.5"
    },
    "attributes": [
      28
    ],
    "unit_impact": 0,
    "minimal_quantity": "1",
    "date_formatted": "",
    "available_date": "",
    "id_image": -1,
    "list": "'28'"
  },
  "224161": {
    "attributes_values": {
      "4": "9"
    },
    "attributes": [
      29
    ],
    "unit_impact": 0,
    "minimal_quantity": "1",
    "date_formatted": "",
    "available_date": "",
    "id_image": -1,
    "list": "'29'"
  }
};
var contentOnly = false;
var Blank = 1;
var Format = 2;
```

Meaning that when I print out s.text. I will get an output of the code above. Small edit: If I try to do `if s.text.strip().startswith('var combinationsFromController'):` it won't find the value and also if I change it the other way around `if 'var combinationsFromController' in s.text.strip():` it will print out the same output as above.

However my issue is that I just want to be able to print out `var combinationsFromController` and skip the rest where I later on can convert the values to a json using json.loads but before that my issue is, How can I print so I can managed to just have the value `var combinationsFromController`?

EDIT: probably solved it!

```
for s in product_li_tags:
            if 'var combinationsFromController' in s.text.strip():
                for line in s.text.splitlines():
                    if line.startswith('var combinationsFromController'):
                        get_full_text = line.strip()
                        get_config = get_full_text.split(" = ")
                        cut_text = get_config[1][:-1]
                        get_json_values = json.loads(cut_text)
```

Comment: If your goal is to parse JavaScript in Python you can consider using an existing library that does that. A number of them are mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390992/javascript-parser-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question you have a string of 121 lines representing 5 javascript variables and you want to obtain a substring containing *only the 2nd variable*.

You can use Python string manipulation as follows:

```
start = special_code.split('\n').index('var combinationsFromController ={')
end   = special_code.split('\n')[start + 1:].index('var contentOnly = false;')
print('\n'.join(lines[start:end + 3]))
```

Using method `str.index` to find occurrences of the javascript variable you need.
**In case the order variables is arbitrary**, i.e. you don't know what is the name of the next variable after the target one, you can still use similar string manipulation to obtain the required substring.

```
lines = special_code.split('\n')
start = lines.index('var combinationsFromController ={')
end   = lines[-1]
for i, line in enumerate(lines[start + 1:]):
    if 'var' in line:
        end = start + i
        break
print('\n'.join(lines[start:end + 1]))
```

Comment: Note that parsing javascript code (or any language with possibly nested statements) with such simple solutions is brittle at best - it's usually better to use a proper parser that won't trip on technically equivalent but textually different code (ie if a space is added between the '=' and the '{' in the first line).

Comment: Oh yeah, Thats very true! So meanwhile I tried to do something different and it apprently worked! I edited my thread. What do you think about that?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers you are totally right. Proper javascript parser is the best choice.

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere, yes your edit might work as well. I would argue is not that clean, maybe a 2 lines solution like my answer or the one using regular expression is cleaner. But you should definitely check some javascript parser as mentioned in other comments

Comment: Yayy! Who knew I would be able to do that but I wouldn't be able to do that with you guys help!

Comment: Yeah forsure, I mean I tried to do the same way as you did but I think I got some errors. So I tried to figure out ish from the point as you wrote and went through there. But I agree. Maybe I should do that afterall.

Comment: if you want to try a javascript parser I would recommend this https://pypi.org/project/slimit/

Comment: Woah! I just tried slimit! Seems to work aswell. A error I got from yours was `ValueError: 'var combinationsFromController ={' is not in list`

Answer (score 1):

using `re` with expression `(\{.*?\});` to capture data between `var combinationsFromController =` and `;var contentOnly = false;`

```
import re

....
print(special_code)
jsonStr = re.search(r'(\{.*?\});', special_code, re.S).group(1)
combinationsFromController = json.loads(jsonStr)

for key in combinationsFromController:
    print(key)
    # 224114
    # 224140
    # 224160
```

Comment: Same caveat as for Alessandro Solbiati's answer: this is brittle at best, and a proper javascript parser would be much more robust.

Comment: Oh yeah, Thats very true! So meanwhile I tried to do something different and it apprently worked! I edited my thread. What do you think about that?