# Find a key inside a script tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

What I'm trying to do is acquire a product ID from a script tag inside an HTML document. Unfortunately, StockX doesn't offer a public API, so I have to scrape the data from an HTML document. Here are my attempts at it (both work):

**Attempt 1**

```
import requests

PRODUCT_URL = 'https://stockx.com/supreme-steiff-bear-heather-grey'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url=PRODUCT_URL, headers=HEADERS).text
PRODUCT_ID = response[response.find('"product":{"id":"')+17:].partition('"')[0]
PRODUCT_NAME = response[response.find('<title>')+7:].partition('<')[0]
```

**Attempt 2**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Gets HTML document
PRODUCT_URL = 'https://stockx.com/supreme-steiff-bear-heather-grey'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}
html_content = requests.get(url=PRODUCT_URL, headers=HEADERS)

# Make BeautifulSoup parser from HTML document
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content.text, 'html.parser')

# Get product name
PRODUCT_NAME = soup.title.text

# Get script tag data with product ID
js_content = soup.find_all('script', type='text/javascript')[9].text
PRODUCT_ID = js_content[50:86]

print(PRODUCT_ID)
```

**Output:**
`884861d2-abe6-4b09-90ff-c8ad1967ac8c`

However, I feel like there is a better approach to this problem instead of just "hard-coding" in where to find the ID.

If you view the page source of the product URL and do a search for `"product":{"id":`, you will find that the ID is inside a nested dictionary that is assigned to an object and inside a  tag.

Is there any better way to go about obtaining the product ID from an HTML document?

EDIT: Here is the content of `html_content`: https://gist.github.com/leecharles50/9b6b11fb458767cabcfc0ed4f961984d

Comment: You should include a minimal example of `html_content.text` - [mcve].

Comment: OP gives you the URL and headers needed to get `html_content`, seems minimal _and_ reproducible to me

Comment: I added a Gist link to the contents of html_content

Comment: This is a nice problem!

Comment: Maybe a regex like ```r'"product":{"id":"(\w{8}-(?:\w{4}-){3}\w{12}){1}"'```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first idea was to parse the JavaScript inside the tag. There is a package called [slimit](https://pypi.org/project/slimit/) that can do this. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25112096/8164958).

However, in your case there is an even easier solution. I searched the DOM for the id you gave (`884861d2-abe6-4b09-90ff-c8ad1967ac8`) and found an occurrence inside the following tag:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        [...]
        "sku" : "884861d2-abe6-4b09-90ff-c8ad1967ac8c",
        [...]
    }
</script>
```

which contains valid JSON. Simply find the tag with BeautifulSoup:

```
tag = soup('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'})[-1]
```

and decode the JSON within:

```
import json
product_id = json.loads(tag.text)['sku']
```

Comment: Ah nice, you beat me to it, although I believe this will fail on certain pages to some of the JSON contents. I'm currently working on getting that aspect figured out.

Comment: This looks promising! Will try to implement this solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by the product URL, this has been tested on multiple product pages.

```py
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#product_url = 'https://stockx.com/supreme-steiff-bear-heather-grey'
product_url = 'https://stockx.com/air-jordan-1-retro-high-shattered-backboard-3'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}

html_content = requests.get(url=product_url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content.text, 'lxml')

script_tags = soup.find_all('script', attrs={'type': 'application/ld+json'})

product_info_text = script_tags[-1].text

# contains a bunch of useful info
product_info_json = json.loads(product_info_text, strict=False)

print(json.dumps(product_info_json, indent=4))

product_sku = product_info_json['sku']

print(product_sku)
```

I will try to implement the use of a `SoupStrainer`.

Comment: I think you forgot a line before `product_info_json = ...` as `product_info_text` is undefined at that point.

Comment: @Seb I thought I had already posted a comment in response, that’s so strange... Anyway, thank you for pointing that out, I probably never would have noticed otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using regex:

```
import requests
import re

product_uuid = re.compile(r'"product":{"id":"(\w{8}-(?:\w{4}-){3}\w{12}){1}"')
product_name = re.compile(r'<title>(.*)</title>')

url = 'https://stockx.com/supreme-steiff-bear-heather-grey'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'
}

content = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if content.ok:
    PRODUCT_NAME = product_name.findall(content.text)[0]
    PRODUCT_UUID = product_uuid.findall(content.text)[0]

    print(PRODUCT_NAME)
    print(PRODUCT_UUID)
```

Slightly hard-coded but easy to adjust and depends only on standard modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scrape on large volumes, you can use the API of [Piloterr](https://www.piloterr.com/integration-category/retail)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32254019)

Comment: Understood @SimasJoneliunas. I'll be careful next time.